# Caching NSView in image with subpixel aliasing

Tags: cocoa, nsview

I want to periodically cache the visible bounds of a `PDFView` in an `NSImage`.  I will later draw the image to the screen, so I'd like it to look exactly the same as the original `PDFView`.  However, I can't get Cocoa to use subpixel anti-aliasing when drawing the text of the `PDFView` in the image context.  It does use plain (i.e., non-LCD) anti-aliasing, but that results in noticeably lighter text.

Is there a portable way to fix this? That is, is there a way cache an `NSView` in an `NSImage` using subpixel anti-aliasing when the monitor supports it?

My code:

```
PDFView *pdfView = ...
NSBitmapImageRep *rep = [pdfView bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect:[pdfView bounds]];

[pdfView cacheDisplayInRect:[pdfView bounds] toBitmapImageRep:rep];

NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:[rep size]];
[image addRepresentation:rep];
```